# where to paste regulatory.db and how?

Tags: debian, firmware

I am dealing with this regulatory.db error:

```
[   14.146398] platform regulatory.0: firmware: failed to load regulatory.db (-2)
[   14.146477] firmware_class: See https://wiki.debian.org/Firmware for information about missing firmware
```

Can you let me know where the lib/firmware is in order to copy that regulatory file?

Comment: See https://wiki.debian.org/Firmware

Answer (score 11):

The regulatory database for wireless adapters is actually `/lib/crda/regulatory.bin`, and it can be found in Debian package `wireless-regdb`. It is in the main part of the Debian package repository, so you'll just need to select it in the package management tool. You should also install the `crda` package, which contains the scripts necessary to load the regulatory information.

(If the `crda` package is not present, the kernel apparently attempts to load it using the generic firmware loading system, which is why you're getting those messages.)

**If you have kernel version 4.15 or newer,** the regulatory database format and location has been changed. It is now loaded using the same mechanism as the firmware files. The new files can be found at https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/sforshee/wireless-regdb/ and you'll need two files, `regulatory.db` and `regulatory.db.p7s`. Place them into `/lib/firmware/` directory.