# Void Linux - Broadcom network adapter [14e4:43a0] appears, but will not connect to a network

Tags: networking, drivers, firmware, broadcom, void-linux

Void Linux with kernel 5.9.16_1.
I'm using NetworkManager on KDE Plasma 5.

Whenever I attempt to connect to a network with this adapter, Plasma says "configuring interface" for a while, and then it says "The WiFi network could not be found."

I installed `broadcom-wl-dkms` from the Void repo, and the device is using the `wl` driver.  This allowed NetworkManager to detect the interface. NetworkManager can use it to see networks, but that's it.

Lines from `sudo dmesg` that I can tell are relevant:

```
[    4.469892] cfg80211: Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates for regulatory database
[    4.471136] cfg80211: Loaded X.509 cert 'sforshee: 00b28ddf47aef9cea7'
[    4.471862] platform regulatory.0: Direct firmware load for regulatory.db failed with error -2
[    4.471863] cfg80211: failed to load regulatory.db
[    4.505347] wl: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    4.505349] wl: module license 'MIXED/Proprietary' taints kernel.
[    4.505349] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
[    4.509529] wl 0000:05:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.527434] wlan0: Broadcom BCM43a0 802.11 Hybrid Wireless Controller 6.30.223.271 (r587334)
[    4.584803] wl 0000:05:00.0 wlp5s0: renamed from wlan0
```

This error is because there is no `/lib/firmware/regulatory.db` file. I installed `dcma` and there is a `/lib/firmware/dcma/regulatory.bin` file. I've looked and I can't find any packages that would have `regulatory.db`. I'm not sure where else I should look for it, or if I can somehow generate it from `regulatory.bin`.

Edit: I downloaded `regulatory.db` and `regulatory.db.p7s` from [this](https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/sforshee/wireless-regdb/) repository and copied them both to `/lib/firmware`

Now this is what I get from `sudo dmesg`:

```
[    4.440473] cfg80211: Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates for regulatory database
[    4.441633] cfg80211: Loaded X.509 cert 'sforshee: 00b28ddf47aef9cea7'
[    4.476573] wl: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    4.476576] wl: module license 'MIXED/Proprietary' taints kernel.
[    4.476577] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
[    4.480880] wl 0000:05:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.498936] wlan0: Broadcom BCM43a0 802.11 Hybrid Wireless Controller 6.30.223.271 (r587334)
[    4.567005] wl 0000:05:00.0 wlp5s0: renamed from wlan0
```

So it looks like `cfg80211` is doing alright, either the necessary firmware is missing or isn't being loaded by anything. How do I get it to load the firmware?

I tried `wpa_supplicant`, but it kept printing `wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-22 retry=1` until I stopped it.

Comment: Simply `grep`ping a word from logs is a Very Bad Technique. It only shows expected error messages, not surprise messages, not context.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

[where to paste regulatory.db and how?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/459518/where-to-paste-regulatory-db-and-how)

you just need to install "crda".